# How to seed Random^ in C++ / CLI with threads?

Tags: multithreading, random, c++-cli

I have a basic program that is using multi-threading. Each thread needs to use different random numbers when the thread procedure is called. I have tried seeding the random number generator within the thread procedure, but I get the same random numbers for each thread. Here is a simple version of what I am doing:

```
public ref class ThreadX
{
public:
    void ThreadProc()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        Console::WriteLine(rand()); //Will output same random numbers
    }
}

int main(){
     ThreadX^ process1 = gcnew ThreadX(gasStationATM);
     Thread^ Thread1 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(process1, &ThreadX::ThreadProc));
     Thread^ Thread2 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(process1, &ThreadX::ThreadProc));
     Thread1->Start();
     Thread2->Start();
}
```

What I originally thought was when the second thread was started, the second thread started the time for the seed would be different and give a different series of random numbers for the second number. How can I seed the srand in C++ CLI so that each thread generates random numbers.

Comment: Make your seed dependent on your thread_id (or any other thread local variables)

Comment: The "CLI" in "C++/CLI" does not mean Command Line Interface.

Comment: I'm afraid the `seed()` isn't thread specific.

Comment: `srand` is not how you seed for `Random^`

Comment: @crashmstr I miss labeled the title. I tried seeding it the same way with Random^ randInt = gcnew Random(); It gives me the same trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your [`Random`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) instance, use the [constructor that lets you specify a seed value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx?cs-lang=cpp). The default constructor uses the current system time as the seed value, so two instances created at the same time will use the same seed, and therefore produce the same sequence of random numbers.

For your seed value, there are two options for specifying different values: You could use some value [unique to the thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) you're running on, or you could use a unique number that you manage.

```
Random^ GetRandom1()
{
    return gcnew Random(Thread::CurrentThread->ManagedThreadId);
}

static int uniqueID = 0;
Random^ GetRandom2()
{
    return gcnew Random(Interlocked::Increment(uniqueID));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a single central RNG in your `main` thread.  As each new thread is created, seed the thread's own RNG with the next number from the central RNG.  This also has the advantage that you can repeat a run exactly if necessary by giving the central RNG a specific seed.  That technique can be useful for repeating (and hence fixing) errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I seed it in the main function, any thread I start gives the same output.

Comment: You need to use the main RNG to generate the seed for the thread's RNG: `thread.srand(main.rand())` or whatever fits your code.

Answer (score 0):

`srand(time(NULL) + rank)` will do the job.

At present, your seed is not thread specific. When all the threads are spawned, they have almost same `time(NULL)`, and so value of seed is same for each thread. To avoid it, you can use rank of thread as seed, or any other thread specific variable.

Comment: What do you mean by adding the rank? Can you elaborate? I did a quick search, but I am not quite sure what you mean by the rank.

Comment: By rank I mean `tid` of thread. Every process have process id (pid), similarly, each thread has it's own thread id (tid). It is also called as rank.